# Are morticians finding huge blood clots as a result of Covid-19 vaccines in otherwise healthy adults that died suddenly?

Tags: covid-19, vaccines

Infowars is reporting that Covid-19 vaccines are causing blood clots.
For example, [here](https://www.infowars.com/posts/must-see-mortician-finds-massive-hand-sized-clots-in-cadavers-after-vax-release/):
[image]

Another article is [here](https://www.infowars.com/posts/must-see-microscopic-video-of-engineered-bio-structures-removed-from-blood-vessels/):
In this article, the story goes into more detail, with Infowars claiming that "Mike Adams and Harrison Smith examine strange rubberband-like tissue removed from suddenly deceased cadavers that appear to be engineered to grow inside the body"

Are these claims accurate? Are morticians finding huge blood clots that are seemingly genetically engineered and a result of the Covid-19 vaccine?

Comment: A pre-emptive reminder (because this discussion happens very frequently) that a notable claim and a reliable claim are not the same thing. InfoWars is by no means a reliable source, but it *is* a notable one.

Comment: The picture in the link shows that "hand-sized" means "finger-sized" in sensationalist journalism. The hand is what is holding the clot, covered by a blue glove.

Comment: For what it's worth, this appears to be based on [this prior article](https://ussanews.com/2022/06/13/microscopic-video-of-engineered-bio-structures-removed-from-blood-vessels/), which eventually leads back to [this video](https://forbiddenknowledgetv.net/worldwide-exclusive-embalmers-find-veins-and-arteries-filled-with-never-before-seen-rubbery-clots/) from January.  These add "board-certified embalmer and funeral director, Richard Hirschman" as the _actual_ source, who is not mentioned in the linked articles (although I didn't watch the videos).